# Getting an ion-fab button to sit just above the ion-footer

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I want my ion-fab button to sit just above the footer. Is there a good way to do this? The general set up of my page is as follows:

```
<ion-header></ion-header>
<ion-content>
     <ion-fab bottom right></ion-fab>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer></ion-footer>
```

Are there css styles I can use to get the fab button right above the footer?

Comment: yes, there are css styles you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on Css position Properties:
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

You can also use @media to use different values depending on the screen size.
As an example:

Html:

```
<ion-fab slot="fixed" class="btm">
    <ion-fab-button>Button</ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

Css:

```
@media(min-width: 768px)
{
  ion-fab.btm
  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 72vh;
    margin-left: 97vw;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px)
{
  ion-fab.btm
  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 72vh;
    margin-left: 82vw;
  }
}
```

Alternative:

```
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
   <ion-fab-button>
   </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```